# (http) Web request provider in coreclr/dnxCore?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, coreclr

Is there a provider available for doing web requests/basic GET downloads in `coreclr`? (`.net core`)

Both `System.Net.Webclient` and `HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse` aren't available, I realize it's aimed at serving content, not consuming, but basic string downloading seems like something that really should have been included?

Am I forgetting something, or is it just straight up not possible?

I can default to full dnx, but would really rather not and lose cross platform compatibility.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use the modern `HttpClient` class from [System.Net.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http/) on NuGet, which supports DNXCore.

Comment: Well there we go then, thanks - Completely skipped my mind.

Comment: `HttpClient` is OK for DNXCore but when you need a PostAsync call HttpContent is not available for `DNX4.5.1` . We have the other one in DNX 4.5.1 at the moment.