# Making calls to an ASP.NET 5 Web API from a C# class library

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I have a Web API that was created with ASP.NET 5.
I have a repository class library (package) that needs to make calls to this web api using some kind of http client.

What would be the correct package to reference if I want to keep everything within ASP.NET 5? I tried referencing: "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client": "5.2.3" but it doesn't work with Platform 5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32211585/1365053

You should use the modern HttpClient class from System.Net.Http on NuGet, which supports DNXCore.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http/

Comment: Alright, I added "System.Net.Http": "4.0.1-beta-23516" and it seems to be working fine. Do you know what happened to ReadAsync by any chance. It isn't available anymore. I guess I have to use ReadAsStringAsync and then convert to Json...

Comment: yes like this:

string response = await new HttpClient()
                .GetStringAsync("uri");

            Car obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Car>(response);

Comment: Got it. and One final thing that you might be able to help me with. What if I do not want my function to return async Task<IList<Customer>> and just IList<Customer> can I still use the async functions? I guess I could do something like Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = client.GetAsync("api/customers"); Does this make sense?

Comment: all http calls in coreclr are async only. but you can always do `GetStringAsync("uri").Result ` or `.Wait()` if you don't want to use async await.